# Qt use parent function in child (C++)

Tags: c++, qt

I am learning Qt with Qt creator and I have a question.

I saw a lot of people asking the same thing but nothing helped me.

I have a MainWindow and in a function i create a subwindow like this :

```
void MainWindow::on_actionAdd_Friend_triggered()
{
    adduser = new addUser(this);
    adduser->show();
}
```

In my MainWindow.h :

```
private:
    addUser *adduser;
```

And I want to access at a function of Mainwindow in adduser.

I have tried to put a getter in addUser (child) and try to get the info after the `adduser->show();` but the child is destroyed so I have access to nothing...

I saw that there is a solution with `conect()` : is this a good solution? or is there another way?

Comment: What do you want to do with `MainWindow` in `addUser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the parent() method to access any other window from your adduser window. The reason is that `parent()` will give you the parent in the window hierarchy and most probably you'll end up getting a proxy window of MainWindow.
Instead, MainWindow should have a slot where it receives added users via a signal from your child window. on_actionAdd_Friend_triggered will have to set up a connection with `connect()` before calling `adduser->show();`